# Can some one explain php's pack and how I might reimplement in java

Tags: java, php

I am trying to move a piece of code in php to java that encodes a payload, but I am having trouble understanding the exactly what php is doing and how I might do it in Java.

I have a line like the following in php:

```
pack('H12CCVV', $id, $x, $y, $z, $w);
```

from reading both the php and pearl docs I think this is saying to Hex 1st 12 characters and 2 unsigned characters then 2 unsigned Shorts, but I am not sure this understanding i correct. I have figured out that the following is true:

```
pack('H12', $id) == pack('H12', $id, $x, $y, $z, $w);
```

which leads me to believe that `$x` & `$y` are encoded as `C` i.e. unsigned char and `$z` & `$w` are encoded as V i.e. unsigned short.

I also believe (but Not 100% and don't know how I might verify)

`pack('H*', $id)` in php is same as `DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(id.getBytes())` in java

would It be simply be to:
1 - get hex of 1st 12 characters of Id as string
2 - append to string the Char of X & Y 
3 - append to string the Short of Z & W
?

if not how should I approach it?

Finally, if someone can help me to figure out how I might verify, I am using PhpStorm and Intellij CE so I can debug but I can't straight copy the  value of pack as a string because the encoding causes an issue, for example this:

```
pack('H12CCVV', $id, $x, $y, $z, $w);
```

results in the following in phpstorm's debugger variables:
[image]